# In this context what is the purpose of 'alert(strings)'

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

> **Question a:**
> (i) Write a JavaScript code fragment that obtains four strings from text fields, stores them in an array, uses the sort function to sort it into ascending lexicographical order, and displays the sorted array in a presentation tag on the HTML page from which the script was invoked. All interactions with the document object model should be done using JQuery. You should assume that the input fields have id attributes id1, id2, id3, and id4, and the presentation tag has the id attribute sorted

Solution I found:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var strings =[$("#id1").val(),$("#id2").val(),$("#id3").val(),$("#id4").val()];
    strings.sort();
    $("#sorted").text(strings);
    alert(strings); 
});
```

I have a question about that solution: What is the `alert(strings);` line for? I know what the `alert` function does but I don't see the question asking for it.

> (ii) Describe how the code produced for part (a) would need to be modified to sort numbers into ascending numerical order

It seems to be the code above already sorts numbers into ascending numerical order, am I wrong?

Comment: "*It seems*" - so what happens when you run it with `"1", "10", "2"`?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the alert(strings); line for?

Just to show the result.

> It seems to be the code above already sorts numbers into ascending numerical order, am I wrong?

That's incorrect. If you don't provide a callback, [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) defaults to a lexicographic sort (loosely speaking, it sorts alphabetically), converting the elements to strings (for the sort comparison only) if necessary:

```js
const a = [3, 10, 7, 20];
a.sort();
console.log(a);
```

Notice how `10` comes before `3`, because the string `"10"` sorts before the string `"3"` in a lexicographic sort, because `"1"` is before `"3"`.